# Which Http module to use with Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm using the latest Angular, I noticed there are 2 modules for http:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Which one should I use?

I'm using observables.

Comment: What is your angular version

Comment: One is a module, the other is a service. They don't serve the same purpose, but they're both part fo the right module to use.

Comment: Angular: 6.1.10

Comment: @Coder you are using **latest angular** which is `7.x.x` currently but you mentioned `6.1.x`

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` is not a module.

Module is

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

As per the latest versions of angular you should use `HttpClientModule`. Because old `httpModule` was deprecated in newer versions (Maybe after v4).

Whereas `HttpClient` is just a class of `HttpClientModule` module. Which has number of methods to use.

> HttpClient is a angular service bundled inside HttpClientModule.

Official Doc about [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule)
and [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)

Comment: do you have a link?

Answer (score -1):

It's high time to switch to **`HttpClientModule`** if you are still using **`HttpClient`**. If your application is with above angular 4, you should use

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

NOTE: **`HttpClient`** is not a module, it was **`HttpModule`** earlier. HttpClient is used in component/service.

Comment: True, but it will confuse him more than anything : if you look at the question, the issue is that he doesn't know the difference between a service and a module